# Meaning of hyphen in Angular tags

Tags: angularjs

I found a bit of code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zcC4v6?p=info) which I don't understand. It's a word cloud where the cloud is added to the page with:

```
<tang-cloud words="words" on-click="test(word)" width="500" height="500"></tang-cloud>
```

This is some how picked up by Angular. What I don't understand is I can find no references to **"tang-cloud"** in the rest of the code. Various **"tangcloud"** but nothing with a hyphen.

I'm totally new to Angular, I've stumbled across another case where this seems to happen, but all the tutorial cases I've seen would have used **"tangcloud"**. If I remove the hyphen it stops working, so I must just be missing something simple.

Thank you

Comment: HTML isn't case sensitive, but JavaScript is.  whenever you refer to `tangcloud` or `tangCloud` in HTML, they will refer to the same thing.  when you want to refer to `tangCloud` specifically, angular converts this to `tang-cloud`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a directive. Since HTML is case-insensitive, angular converts the `tangCloud` directive to `tang-cloud` to be readable by HTML.

The tangCloud directive in tangCloud.js is where you'll find the code for that.

Edit: Just to follow up, you see the bit that says `restrict: 'E'`? That tells angular that you can use the directive as a custom element. When you make a directive camelcase, like `tangCloud`, angular will automatically convert it to `tang-cloud`.

```
.directive('tangCloud', ['$interpolate', '$compile', '$timeout', function ($interpolate, $compile, $timeout) {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            width: '=',
            height: '=',
            words: '=',
            onClick: '&',
            spin: '='
        },

        template: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            var isClickable = angular.isDefined(tAttrs.onClick);

            var clickAttr = isClickable ? 'ng-click="onClick({word : entry.word, id : entry.id})"' : '';

            return "<div class='tangcloud'>" +
                "<span ng-repeat='entry in words'" + clickAttr + ">{{entry.word}}</span>" +
                "</div>";
        },

        compile: function (elem) {
            elem.children().children()
                .addClass('tangcloud-item-' + $interpolate.startSymbol() + 'entry.size' + $interpolate.endSymbol())
                .addClass('tangcloud-item-hidden');

            return function (scope, elem) {
                var centerX = scope.width / 2;
                var centerY = scope.height / 2;
                var outOfBoundsCount = 0;
                var takenSpots = [];

                if (scope.words) {
                    scope.words = shuffleWords(scope.words);
                    determineWordPositions();
                }

                function shuffleWords(array) {
                    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                        var temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp;
                    }
                    return array;
                }

                function determineWordPositions() {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var trendSpans = elem.children().eq(0).children();
                        var length = trendSpans.length;

                        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            setWordSpanPosition(trendSpans.eq(i));
                        }
                    });
                }

                function setWordSpanPosition(span) {
                    var height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(span[0]).lineHeight, 10);
                    var width = span[0].offsetWidth;
                    var spot = setupDefaultSpot(width, height);
                    var angleMultiplier = 0;

                    while (spotNotUsable(spot) && outOfBoundsCount < 50) {
                        spot = moveSpotOnSpiral(spot, angleMultiplier);
                        angleMultiplier += 1;
                    }

                    if (outOfBoundsCount < 50) {
                        takenSpots.push(spot);
                        addSpanPositionStyling(span, spot.startX, spot.startY);
                    }

                    outOfBoundsCount = 0;
                }

                function setupDefaultSpot(width, height) {
                    return {
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        startX: centerX - width / 2,
                        startY: centerY - height / 2,
                        endX: centerX + width / 2,
                        endY: centerY + height / 2
                    };
                }

                function moveSpotOnSpiral(spot, angleMultiplier) {
                    var angle = angleMultiplier * 0.1;
                    spot.startX = centerX + (1.5 * angle) * Math.cos(angle) - (spot.width / 2);
                    spot.startY = centerY + angle * Math.sin(angle) - (spot.height / 2);
                    spot.endX = spot.startX + spot.width;
                    spot.endY = spot.startY + spot.height;
                    return spot;
                }


                function spotNotUsable(spot) {

                    var borders = {
                        left: centerX - scope.width / 2,
                        right: centerX + scope.width / 2,
                        bottom: centerY - scope.height / 2,
                        top: centerY + scope.height / 2
                    };

                    for (var i = 0; i < takenSpots.length; i++) {
                        if (spotOutOfBounds(spot, borders) || collisionDetected(spot, takenSpots[i])) return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                function spotOutOfBounds(spot, borders) {
                    if (spot.startX < borders.left ||
                        spot.endX > borders.right ||
                        spot.startY < borders.bottom ||
                        spot.endY > borders.top) {
                        outOfBoundsCount++;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                function collisionDetected(spot, takenSpot) {
                    if (spot.startX > takenSpot.endX || spot.endX < takenSpot.startX) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return !(spot.startY > takenSpot.endY || spot.endY < takenSpot.startY);
                }

                function addSpanPositionStyling(span, startX, startY) {
                    var style = "position: absolute; left:" + startX + "px; top: " + startY + "px;";
                    span.attr("style", style);
                    span.removeClass("tangcloud-item-hidden");
                }
            };


        }
    };

    return directive;
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The tang-cloud directive is defined as tangCloud - take this example from the angular [docs for directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

app.js

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
     template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div my-customer></div>
</div>
```

See the Normalization section in [this part](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives) of the docs. Try searching `'tangCloud'`